# Could not hit breakpoint in source code in a Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, breakpoints

The following image shows my problem:

[image]

I cannot put a breakpoint on source code. This problem happens when maven download source code.

Comment: Please, can you add more details like versions..

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a **`.class` file with attached source** (recognizable by the outline *J* editor icon). Probably this `.class` file was compiled **without line debug information** which is required for line breakpoints.

Either you have to **recompile** this class with line debug information or **use a method breakpoint** instead.

Comment: I use jetbrain IDEA ,there is not bug on it .I think it may be eclipse's bug

Comment: @陈伟钿 As far as I know, in such cases (without line debug information but with source code available) IDEA recompiles the code with line debug information to be able to add breakpoints. In contrast, Eclipse does not use this "hack", but executes the unmodified bytecode and therefore no breakpoints can be set.